# Child Relationships in Javascript Remoting

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript-remoting, remote-action

I'm using Visualforce Remoting to get information about a Contact.  I want to get a specific Attachment related to the Contact at the same time (which is linked through ParentId).

When I return the Contact, the result does not seem to include information about the child objects.

My Contacts.page

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.MyContactsController.getContact}',

    contactId,

    function(result, event){

            console.log(result);
        }

);
```

RemoteAction:

```
@RemoteAction
    global static Contact getContact(Id contactId){

        Contact selContact = [SELECT Id, (Select Id from Attachments where ParentId = :contactId and Name = 'Contact Picture'), Name, FirstName, LastName  FROM Contact WHERE Id=:contactId limit 1];
        return selContact;
    }
```

console.log returns:

> result: Object
>
> FirstName: "John"
>   Id: "003U000000s2RmEIAU" 
>   LastName: "Smith" 
>   Name: "John Smith"

and there is no Attachments array.  I know I could do it with another RemoteAction, or by using a Wrapper Class, but I thought this would work.

Comment: The query returns the attachment results when you execute it through and IDE/dev console/workbench right ?

Comment: Can you verify that there are child attachments for the specific Contact you requested?

Comment: Gah.  I queried the wrong Contact.  With the right one the Attachments array is indeed specified.  Should I delete my question?

Comment: @GeorgeS. I would rather post the comment as answer and mark it solved. Would help others who stop by later

Comment: Answer it yourself, then accept your answer. Then you can get the booty and your goof is searchable for eternity :D

Comment: So now I know the secret of those with high rep - make a lot of goofs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had queried with the wrong Contact ID, with a Contact who did not have Attachments.  This naturally does not return a blank Attachments array, but rather no array at all.